# How not refresh table when checkbox is selected

Tags: oracle, checkbox, oracle-adf

I have a table consisting of several columns. The first column is comprised of checkbox allows the user to select one or more rows. If at least one line is selected a button is enable.
The problem I have is that the table "suffers" refresh each time the user selects a checkbox. In the column that contains the checkbox have autosubmit = true, immediate = true and partialtrigger enableButtons = ().
But not table does not have any of the properties to true.

Answer (score 0):

The table will not refresh just because checkbox has autosubmit to true. Make sure table does not have any partialTriggers and there is no action getting fired which is causing table/whole page to refresh. I believe you are using actionListener of checkbox to enable and disable the button. You can also try client listener on checkbox for that purpose and see if that makes any difference.

On the other hand, if your concern is more about loosing all check box values when any check box is checked, due to table refresh then try to use the transient attribute from EO for your check box values. This way even if the table is refreshed you will not loose your check box values.

Comment: I dont have valuechangelistener in table, just in column with checkbox. I have refreshcondition=false but not work..

Comment: Would be helpful to understand the problem if you could share the jspx/jsff code for your table.

Comment: <af:table value="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.collectionModel}" var="row"
                                  rows="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.rangeSize}"
                                  emptyText="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.viewable ? 'No data to display.' : 'Access Denied.'}"
                                  fetchSize="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.rangeSize}" rowBandingInterval="0" id="t1"
                                  binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_OrderSearch.t1}"
                                  autoHeightRows="100" immediate="true">

Comment: </f:facet>
                            </af:column>
                            <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.hints.OrderNo.name}" sortable="false"
                                       headerText="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.hints.OrderNo.label}" id="c2" width="111">
                                <af:commandLink text="#{row.OrderNo}" id="cl1"
                                                inlineStyle="text-decoration:underline; font-size:99%;" action="goToOrderDetail">

Comment: <af:setPropertyListener type="action" from="#{row.OrderNo}"
                                                            to="#{pageFlowScope.pOrderNo}"/>
                                </af:commandLink>
                            </af:column>
                            <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.hints.CreateDatetime.name}"
                                       sortable="false"
                                       headerText="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.hints.CreateDatetime.label}" id="c3"
                                       width="110

Comment: It's too long my code for table but columns are equals .

Comment: You did not share the code for column which has check boxes in it

Comment: <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.hints.Selected.name}" sortable="false"
                                   headerText="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.hints.Selected.label}" id="c1" width="109"
                                   displayIndex="-1">
                            <af:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{row.bindings.Selected.inputValue}"

Comment: label="#{row.bindings.Selected.label}"
                                                      shortDesc="#{bindings.OrdlocDlvrVO1.hints.Selected.tooltip}"
                                                      id="sbc1" autoSubmit="true"
                                                      valueChangeListener="#{backingBeanScope.backing_OrderSearch.enableButtons}"

Comment: immediate="true"/>
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <af:outputFormatted value="TOTAL" id="of2"
                                                    binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_OrderSearch.of2}"
                                                    inlineStyle="font-weight:bold;"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </af:column>

Comment: that's it amishra. this is my column with checkbox

Comment: Did you try immediate="false" on your table?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting immediate="false" for your table.